# How do I get Google admob to verify my identity?

Tags: admob, verification

On reaching the payment threshold Google started sending messages that stated my payment remains on hold until I verify my identity.

I tried doing so twice by uploading my national identity card (that's the only government issued credential I have currently)

But it kept failing, and I learnt I only have one attempt left. Please what do I do.

Comment: I have uploaded my id card and it's failed. They only give me one chance. Now I can't verify my identity anymore and the ads stop showing. This is so ridiculous! I didn't even know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Did it eventually work? How?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t been rejected yet hopefully I don’t i have submitted my ids like 2 days ago but I haven’t got a response I actually don’t know how long it takes to get verified. But for your situation I guess you should go to your mail and make sure the details you use to open your mail is the same as the details on your id and what you provided on your admob. You could also check their YouTube channel and check for the tutorial on sending verification. You can also text their support for guide.